# VS2019 how to restart npm that's automatically started on local build

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, npm, visual-studio-2019

I've started my project on react .net core 3.1 template (VS2019). When I build project it also run 'npm run start' automatically in the background.

Is there any way to stop/restart npm without restarting visual studio 2019?

Comment: As far as I know, the asp.net core react app will not call npm run start each time when you build the project.   If you want to publish it will call the `npm run build`. All the setting which is related with the npm is inside the your project's csproj file.

Comment: That's weird because when I hit ctrl-f5 straight after opening my react project solution, clientapp static page is already running on port 61530 and even the auto-refresh on code change works as well. That's without me having to run npm run start manually. if i manually run npm run start - it opens page on localhost:3000.

Comment: but maybe the solution is to ignore the development server started by visual studio 2019 (on port 61530) and manually run it so i have control over it. But if anyone knows how this works i'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it. It's in startup.cs in Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) method.

```
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```